# elements position and display unexpected

Tags: html, css, css-float, background-image

I believe that I have incorrectly used a combination of float, margin and background image. The issue is a white gap at the bottom of my screen when viewing html doc.

The desired outcome is to have no white gap at the bottom of the screen - where the background image starts at the bottom.

When viewing the page with following code:

```
* {outline: solid 1px;}
```

you can see that there is a line along the bottom which must be the html or body element. Whats the space between that and the bottom of the screen? How do I remove it?

Here is the URL major thanks to anyone who helps me solve this headache: http://tinyurl.com/7ywoqpf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
html{
    min-height:100%;
}
```

Hope this is what you meant.

Comment: that solves the problem when on a larger screen but when working of my Mac the problem remains?

Comment: what problem? i'm working on my macbook air right now but I don't see a problem.

Comment: really? Um, OK I wonder if it's a problem with my browser only - could you send a screen shot of bottom right?

Comment: aaah I think I know what you mean. edited my answer; try `min-height:100%`!

Comment: to put the question another way, the aim is to have a situation where no matter the users screen size, the two background images are in the top right and bottom left - if you play around with your browsers zoom function does the html heighht 100% fix still work? I'm finiding it's not but maybe thats just firefox on a mac?